# Using random number generator package in Python

Tags: python, random

I came across a random number generator package at this link.

I want to use this package in Python. I am a beginner in Python, and am not able to understand where to even begin.

Comment: It's a c++ library so you'll probably have to write a python wrapper for it if one doesn't already exist

Comment: Python has a built in module [Random]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html
that can be used to generate random numbers...

Comment: Why do you say that Mersenne Twister (Python's default PRNG) is not suitable for Monte Carlo?

Comment: In response to your Edit2 - MT19937 generated values are not independent, but then neither are the values produced by any other pure PRNG.  Its performance on statistical tests for uniformity and for serial correlation is far better than most alternatives people have historically used for Monte Carlo.  Unless you're evaluating k-tuples for k > 623, you're almost certainly not going to be impacted by the issues Pierre L'Ecuyer talks about in the paper cited on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The [reikna](http://reikna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/computations.html#module-reikna.cbrng) package is based on the Random123 source code, and generates CBRNG random numbers.

Random numbers can be generated straight from python using the [random library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), for example:

```
a = random.randint(0,100)
# sets a to a random integer (whole number) between 0 and 100 (inclusive)
```

If you require cryptographic strength randomness then this can be implemented using the [os library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom), for example:

```
b = os.random(10)
# sets b to a string of 10 random bytes
```

For more complex uses the [numpy random routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) may be what you're looking for:

```
c = numpy.random.beta(a, b)
# sets c to a random sample from a Beta distribution, with a = α and b = β.
```

Comment: How about using numbers generated from [random atmospheric noise](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/RandomDotOrg-0.2.1/docs/System-Random-Atmosphere.html)?

Comment: Alternatively [this library](https://github.com/hathix/true-random) claims to be a true-random number generator (although I find that hard to believe)...

Comment: But as I said, os.random is used cryptographically, so I suspect it generates random numbers in a more interesting way then the Mersenne Twister.

Comment: Or even better, the [Reikna Package](http://reikna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/computations.html#module-reikna.cbrng) has CBRNG functions, and is in fact based on the source code for the Random123 package.

Comment: For os.random you can't recreate same random numbers as it ignores the seeds.

Comment: I understand your issue now; and I think that the [reikna package](http://reikna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/computations.html#module-reikna.cbrng) may be what you're looking for?